# Run GUI Application from web-based terminal emulator ubuntu18.04/Jupyter Notebook

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, xorg, jupyter, ipython

I have installed a fully-functional terminal emulator in an IPython/Jupyter notebook. This is useful for notebook environments that don't provide shell access. The terminal is used inside the browser. All commands are executed correctly. But, there is a problem with opening a GUI application from the web-based terminal.

[image: Web-based terminal screen]

For instance, executing `xclock` inside the terminal does not open the application window. Is there any feasible solution to open GUI application from web terminals?

Comment: I've never used Jupyter myself, but try `DISPLAY=:0 xclock`?

Comment: @wjandrea: Thank You. It Works.

Comment: @wjandrea: Strange though it may see, the DISPLAY=:0 command works for one time and after a reboot, the problem again starts. Do you have any suggestion?